# custom path directory for subdomain in directadmin

Tags: apache, subdomain, directadmin

I use directadmin.

I need to have a subdomain with `shop` name, that point to `web` directory.

I use below code in this option: `admin > Custom Httpd Configurations`

```
|*if SUB="shop"|
|?DOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/public_html/web|
|*endif|
```

But this is output code:

```
DocumentRoot /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/web/shop
```

This is because in the sub host template file (`/usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/virtual_host2_sub.conf`) wrote this: `DocumentRoot |DOCROOT|/|SUB|`

I need to this correction output:

```
DocumentRoot /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/web
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already resolved the problem, anyway maybe this helps somebody else. I found [this](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=199), it basically says that you should copy `virtual_host2_sub.conf` and `virtual_host2_secure_sub.conf` files from:

```
/usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/
```

to

```
/usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
```

Then, you should edit your custom files, changing the following lines:

```
|?DOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/public_html|
```

to

```
|?DOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/public_html/`SUB`|
```

Then:

```
|?CGI=ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ `DOCROOT`/`SUB`/cgi-bin/|
```

to

```
|?CGI=ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ `DOCROOT`/cgi-bin/|
```

and

```
DocumentRoot |DOCROOT|/|SUB|
```

to

```
DocumentRoot |DOCROOT|
```

Answer (score 0):

With access level "Admin" choose from menu GUI "Server manager" -> Custom HTTPD configurations" -> choose your domain -> in the top right corner click "Customize".

In the first textarea add this:

```
|*if SUB="mysubdomain"|
|?SDOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/public_html/`SUB`/public|
|*endif|
```

Simply change the path "public" if you wish.
Aftewards check "/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/httpd.conf" if everything's OK and "service httpd restart" (I think DA doesn't restart httpd after you save your custom configuration).

This works from 1.59.5 version